# How update entity using lombok builder?

Tags: java, quarkus

The only method that are not working is UPDATE. My resource code:

```
@Path("/campaigns")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CampaignResource {

    @Inject
    CampaignService campaignService;

    // ...

    @PUT
    @Transactional
    @Path("{id}")
    public Optional<Campaign> update(@PathParam("id") UUID id, Campaign entity) {
        return campaignService.updateCampaign(id, entity);
    }

    // ...

  }
```

Service code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CampaignService {

    // ...

    @Inject
    CampaignRepository campaignRepository;

    public Optional<Campaign> updateCampaign(UUID id, Campaign entity) {
        return campaignRepository.update(id, entity);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Repository code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CampaignRepository implements BaseRepository<Campaign> {

    // ...

    public Optional<Campaign> find(final UUID id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(findById(id));
    }

    public Optional<Campaign> update(final UUID id, final Campaign entityUpdate) {
        return find(id).map(entity -> entity.toCampaign(entityUpdate));
    }

    // ...

}
```

Domain/Entity code:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})

@Entity
@Table(name = "core_campaign")
public class Campaign {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    public String name;

    // ...

    @Builder
    public Campaign(final UUID id, final String name/**, ... */) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        // ...
    }

    public Campaign toCampaign(Campaign entity) {
        return Campaign.builder()
            .name(entity.getName())
            // ...
            .build();
    }

}
```

Yes, my mistake is when persist, help me solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you never actually update the entity. You fetch the entity from the database, then you return a new instance from the builder inside the entity, but the fields of the fetched entity is never updated.

AFAIK, you have two choices:

1. You can call repository.save(returnedCampaign) on the returned Campaign object from your "toCampaign()" function
2. You can create an update method inside of your Campaign object, something similar to

this:

```
public Campaign update(Campaign entity) {
    this.name = entity.getName()
    // ...
    return this;
}
```

Since this is happening inside of @Transactional, the changes you make to the entity should be automatically stored.